# Necessity of past perfect?

Tags: past-tense

The....... has been in existence for about three and a half years now, while before that Kai **had been** a member of a group called ......., and even before that **was** also involved with another group called........

Why for the most recent event the author used past perfect and for the least recent event he used past simple, he should have done the contrary or simply sticked to past simple as before indicates which event comes first

Comment: Do you have the context for this? Because I would almost suspect it's just tense-laziness? http://ask.metafilter.com/253668/What-has-happened-to-the-past-perfect-tense

Comment: It is an article from banana mag spring 2016

Comment: I couldn't find a copy of the article online....

Answer (score 1):

The sentence sounds just right to a native speaker. Three things happened in the order of A, B, and C. The sentence is set as a flashback, using order C, B, A.

The verb *had been* (action **B**) contrasts with "The X *has been* ...for three years now" (action **C**). The words *even before that* define the order of time, so using *was also* (action **A**) is clear enough to tell us what happened before what. Action **A** is the oldest action.

Answer (score 0):

What is grammatically correct is the past perfect. I suspect banana mag is not the best source from which to learn English. I too am a native speaker, and the quoted sentence sounds either lazy or uneducated or colloquial to me. The most likely is intentionally colloquial; in speech, the distinction between past and past perfect may not be given the attention accorded to it in formal writing. I doubt the writer will have a career at the New Yorker, but I also doubt that his intended audience is the New Yorker's.